# Как запустить асинхронный метод в отдельном потоке, не дожидаясь его выполнения?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, async-await

Есть метод:

```
public async Task StartListeningAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    _listener.Start();

    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var client = await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        var thread = new Thread(async () => await ProcessClientAsync(client, stoppingToken));
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

Здесь `_listener` - это объект стандартного класса `TcpListener`. Задача состоит в том, чтобы обрабатывать отдельного клиента в отдельном потоке. Обработка клиента может длиться очень долго, пока не пропадет соединение (дней 5, например). Метод обработки клиента `ProcessClientAsync` - асинхронный (можно его, в принципе, сделать синхронным). Мне необходимо запускать этот метод в отдельном потоке. На текущий момент я это делаю через `new Thread`. Мне сказали, что после первого `await` внутри метода `ProcessClientAsync` поток вернет управление наружу, из-за чего поток обработки завершится (обсуждалось это [здесь](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115321/discussion-on-answer-by-pavel-mayorov-----)).

Есть еще вариант использовать `Task.Run`:

```
_listener.Start();

while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    var client = await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
    Task.Run(() => ProcessClientAsync(client, stoppingToken), stoppingToken);
}
```

Но на такой вариант компилятор предупреждает:

> **Warning CS4014**    Because this call is not awaited, execution of the
> current method continues before the call is completed. Consider
> applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.

**Вопрос:** Как все же будет правильно в моем случае запустить метод обработки клиента `ProcessClientAsync` в отдельном потоке? Этот метод *желательно* оставить асинхронным. Если его нельзя оставить асинхронным, то прошу, пожалуйста, объяснить, почему.

Comment: Совсем не ожидать не рекомендуется, так как метод может вернуть исключение, и без ожидания его не достать. Но вы можете записать его в переменную типа `Task` и ожидаеть его там, где критично. `Task t = ProcessClientAsync(client, stoppingToken)`. И где-нибудь в другом месте кода `await t`. Если же вы уверены в том, что делаете, и хочется просто успокоить компилятор, можете вот так `_ = ProcessClientAsync(client, stoppingToken)`. `Task.Run`/`Thread.Start` для запуска асинхронной операции не требуется и является излишеством.

Comment: Есть еще рабочий вариант реализации вашей задачи - паттерн проектирования Producer/Consumer. Реализаций много разных, [вот одна из них](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/250491/226545), даже с ограничением на количество одновременно выполняемых задач консьюмером.

Comment: @aepot спасибо, кое-какие вещи прояснились. И все же, остается вопрос: как правильно запустить метод, чтобы он выполнялся в отдельном потоке? Просто вызвать метод, который мне вернет Task, и забыть про него? Будет ли этот метод выполнен в отдельном потоке? Можете, пожалуйста, поделиться ссылкой, где можно прочитать о поведении программы при вызове асинхронного метода без `await`?

Comment: _как правильно запустить метод, чтобы он выполнялся в отдельном потоке?_ В лоб вот так: `Task t = Task.Run(async () => await ...)`. Но это реально выглядит как костыль. Обычно такое делают, когда асинхронный метод написан криво, а переписать нет возможности.

Comment: @aepot окей, кажется, я понял. Мне нужно сделать метод `ProcessClientAsync` - синхронным, т.к. он выполняется в своем отдельном потоке, и ему не нужно никуда возвращать управление. Все верно?

Comment: @aepot за ссылку с реализацией - спасибо :)

Comment: А нужно ли ему в отдельный поток, вы уверены? [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) - здесь описывается разница между I/O-bound и CPU-bound операциями, сфокусируйтесь на том, в чем она заключается. Затем определите, к чему относится ваш асинхронный метод. Если он I/O - вам не нужны потоки.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115338/discussion-between-andrei-khotko-and-aepot).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перестаньте думать потоками! Нет, не так...

### Перестаньте уже думать потоками!

Вы в своём вопросе исходите из того, что у ваш асинхронный метод выполняется в каком-то конкретном потоке, и вам нужно этот поток сменить. Но истина в том, что большую часть времени ваш асинхронный метод не выполняется ни в одном потоке!

Как устроен типичный асинхронный код обработки клиента? Примерно так:

```cs
async Task ProcessClientAsync(TcpClient client, CancellationToken token) {
    while (true) {
        await ReadRequestFrom(client, token);
        ProcessRequest();
        await SendReplyToClient(client, token);
    }
}
```

Большую часть времени (те самые 5 суток из вопроса) вы просто ждёте поступления данных из сокета. Это самое "ожидание" с точки зрения кода - это просто запись где-то в системных таблицах о том, что когда данные придут - надо уведомить вас. Ни один поток не заблокирован ожиданием. Вы не можете ждать данных от клиента в отдельном потоке потому, что [никакого потока нет](https://habr.com/ru/post/216659/).

Когда данные придут - выполнение вашего метода в любом случае продолжится в пуле потоков (есть варианты с написанием собственных планировщиков задач - но вряд ли у вас получится написать планировщик лучше системного).

Теперь немного слов о долгих задачах, которыми иногда пугают новичков, и о том, что не следует занимать пул потоков надолго. Так вот, "долгая задача" - это задача, которая занимается активными вычислениями. Ваши 5 дней ни один из потоков пула не занят, поэтому `ProcessClientAsync` не является долгой задачей. А вот `ProcessRequest` "долгим" в редких случаях может и оказаться. Если так и произошло - можно сказать об этом системному планировщику задач при помощи вот такой конструкции:

```cs
async Task ProcessClientAsync(TcpClient client, CancellationToken token) {
    while (true) {
        await ReadRequestFrom(client, token);
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessRequest(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        await SendReplyToClient(client, token);
    }
}
```

Заметьте: внутри переданного в `Task.Factory.StartNew` замыкания нет оператора `await`. Так и должно быть. Если вам понадобилось там внутри написать `await` - значит, вы ошибочно выбрали "долгую" задачу!

---

Наконец, про запуск `ProcessClientAsync` без ожидания. Капитан Очевидность подсказывает, что для запуска без ожидания достаточно ничего не ждать:

```cs
    ProcessClientAsync(client, token);
```

Иногда бывает, что `ProcessClientAsync` не сразу "уходит" в ожидание данных, а выполняет какие-нибудь "подготовительные" работы, во время которых лучше бы уже начинать ждать следующее подключение. В таком случае следует использовать `Task.Run`:

```cs
    Task.Run(() => ProcessClientAsync(client, token));
```

Оба варианта допустимы, главное - чтобы не было оператора `await`.

Теперь почему "ругается" компилятор. Компилятор ругается потому, что

1. обычно забытый `await` - это всё-таки ошибка;
2. задача может "упасть" - и было бы неплохо как-нибудь об этом узнать.

Вторая проблема решается, к примеру, логами. Первая проблема проблемой не является, но компилятор можно "заткнуть" сменив тип возвращаемого значения:

```cs
async void ProcessClientAsync(TcpClient client, CancellationToken token) {
    try {
        while (true) {
            await ReadRequestFrom(client, token);
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessRequest(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            await SendReplyToClient(client, token);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // вывод в лог
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень понятно объяснили! Один вопрос по поводу `Task.Run`. `Task.Run` все равно ведь запустит метод в отдельном потоке, верно? Тогда в чем отличие будет между `new Thread` и `Task.Run`? Лишь в том, что Task.Run возьмет поток из пула?

Comment: В моем случае будет лучше все же вызвать метод без `await`. Да, это то поведение, которое мне нужно

Comment: @AndreiKhotko да, `Task.Run` возьмет поток из пула

Comment: @AndreiKhotko `new Thread` спавнит новый поток, `Task.Run` - берет из пула потоков. Если спящий свободный поток есть пуле - запуск операции в таком потоке, если я не ошибаюсь, будет = ~1ms, а спавн нового потока - очень дорогая операция для CPU = ~30ms. А теперь представьте, вам нужно выполнить миллион операций, каждая с временем выполнения 5ms. Сколько времени процессора будет потрачено на спавн новых потоков и сколько на выполнение полезного кода?

Comment: @aepot да, КПД упадет до неприличных значений :)

Comment: @AndreiKhotko вот еще старая, но прекрасная статья о том, как работает асинхронность - [ссылка](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: @aepot вообще-то в ответе есть ссылка на её перевод...

Comment: Ок, просто я в основном читаю по-английски.